# virtualbox pinging from one subnet to another

Tags: linux, virtualbox, subnet

I'm using virtualbox and I have 3 virtual machines, there's the middle vm which is a Linux Fedora 20 which has two interfaces connecting each to one subnet, the other two vms is one also a Fedora 20 Linux and a Windows XP.

I can't ping from one subnet to another, like to/from Windows XP to the other Linux vm on the other subnet, like the middle machine wont route the icmp ping requests. Is there a setting on virtualbox that I should change for it to work?

The machine in the middle has actually 3 interfaces, one NAT to connect to the Internet and the other two are host-only adapter to connect to each subnet, I also can't access the Internet from the other vms, I thought the other vms would be able to access the Internet through this middle Linux vm but they wont.

Is there a setting on Linux or virtualbox that I should know. I should know these things and I feel embarrassed to ask, I couldn't find proper answers on googling. I appreciate any help, thanks :).

Comment: Your middle machine needs to be setup as a router. [This question](http://askubuntu.com/q/376717/42822) has instructions for Ubuntu.  It may be easier, however to use a distribution like [pfSense](https://www.pfsense.org/) that is designed to function as a router.

Comment: Just to say that my problem is solved, I did download an iso of pfSense and I learned how to do the configuration I needed for my environment and so I did and now I have a router in the middle, things are working. Thank you man! I think I'll download a book on pfSense, another learning curve for me :)!